# Generate custom viewflipper

Tags: android, viewflipper

Is it possible to generate a viewflipper, which shows a view for 1 second and the other view for 3 seconds and the other for 9, ...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to accomplish this to use a [`Timer`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Timer.html) that calls ViewFlipper's `showNext()` method after the given time has passed. Also, you can set up automatic flipping and set the interval manually through [`setFlipInterval`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ViewFlipper.html#setFlipInterval%28int%29).

Comment: Thanks for the answers. I've tried the second way:
setFlipInterval works if you want to set the same time interval for all of the views. I've tried the first answer as well, but I'm not sure if I've used it correctly. Could you show me a simple example how to do that?

Comment: Thanks again. I've tried that with another thread in Viewflipper and it works.